Ethernet coupler implementation on PCB - whether to use magnetics (transformer) or not?
I need to implement a sort of coupler on a PCB which has other things running, but without any connection to an Ethernet circuit (see drawing).
One end of this 'coupler' connects (using a suitably rated UDP cable, ~ 4 inches (10 cm)), to a motherboard's Ethernet port (which obviously has a transformer, or the RJ45 is MagJack or with ICM, 2.5 G at least); and the other end of the coupler connects to another external network device (switch/another PC etc, which obviously is magnetically coupled too) via another Ethernet cable.

My questions:

Whether the connectors on my PCB that implement this coupler require transformers on each, or any of the RJ45s? In the picture, these RJ45s are called CN2 and CN3. The routing on the PCB has short lengths — less than 2 inches (5 cm) — and will be differentially routed with length matching and controlled impedance.

Even if I do not need to use transformer coupling between CN2 and CN3 (given that there are no active devices between them, and that terminal devices are magnetically coupled) then can I still use one (CN3) with built-in magnetics? The reason being parts with USB+RJ45 and without integrated magnetics are rarer (for higher speed grades) than with magnetics. If yes, what do I do with center taps on the primary side of the integrated transformer? The ground available is obviously not the same (or may have a very long loop) as that of the PHY inside the motherboard where the circuit is originating.

Any problem if both CN2 and CN3 are connectors with integrated magnetics (for same reason listed above)? If I can do so, then again, what do I do with the center taps on the primary of the integrated magnetics?


Thanks in advance!


Whether the connectors on my PCB that implement this coupler require
transformers on each, or any of the RJ45s?

The transformers are needed if you have isolation. You don't need isolation because you don't have anything on the board that is going to connect to the ethernet.
You can think of the connection on the board like a wire straight through the PCB, as long as it's impedance controlled you should be fine.

Thanks  I thought so too - but my Q(2) and Q(3) are - what if I do add magnetics on one or both of the connectors on my PCB? Is there any issue?
Simply because connectors with integrated magnetics are easily available for the other preferences I have (USB+Ethernet stacked, with USB3.2, Ethernet 2.5G or higher)
